# .htaccess : what is wrong with this rule?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

may you please tell me where is my fault ?

```
RewriteRule ^project/([^.]+)/$ /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

i get Internal Server Error everytime i apply it

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
127.0.0.1/wordpress/project/43928fdsf
redirects to
127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=43928fdsf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is fine which would suggest `mod_rewrite` is not installed/working/turned on. Change your code to look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^project/([^.]+)/$ /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That should stop there being any 500 errors (if they were indeed `mod_rewrite` related). If your URL rewrites still don't work then you don't have `mod_rewrite` installed/enabled, in which case you can [install and enable it](http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/enable-mod-rewrite-on-apache).

UPDATE

You have a forward slash at the end o your RewriteRule but you want to match a URL like 127.0.0.1/wordpress/project/43928fdsf, which has no forward slash at the end. Just remove the forward slash and the rule should match:

```
RewriteRule ^project/([^.]+)$ /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

From then on if you're still getting a 500 error then try printing the `$_GET` variables at the top of your PHP file, then call `exit()` and see if you still have the problem. This should help to narrow down whether the problem is with PHP or Apache.

Comment: thank you for your answer im using mamp and i just enabled mod_rewrite, but i want to make sure the rule will do the job if the user request http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/project/43928fdsf it will redirect him to http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=43928fdsf right ?

Comment: I've added a bit to the answer above, hopefully that'll help

Comment: thank you so much for your help, i tried my best but the problem seems from .htaccess i tried to echo hello or just plain html and still internal server error and not on this page all wordpress get internal server error, much appreciated

Comment: after a long searching session i found that i have something wrong in my rule "pr" in my code is 2 words it's like "p r" so that break the rule, underscore saved my day, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match a single URL part with that group then you are doing it wrong because `[^.]+` will also match `/`. E.g.: `project/a/b/c/` will also match => `$1` will be `a/b/c`

On another note, have you checked what groups you're capturing? And if those values that you then send through parameter `id` are not causing `cp.php` to crash?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i want the following  127.0.0.1/wordpress/project/43928fdsf it will redirects to 127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=43928fdsf

Comment: What happens when you call `127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=43928fdsf` directly in your browser? If it works then there's a problem with the rule, if you see the same server error then there's an issue with the `cp.php` page.

Comment: meaning you called `127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pr/cp.php?id=43928fdsf` in your browser and it worked?

Comment: OK, then there may be a problem with the mod_rewrite installation/configuration